# Task '--ship' is not in your gulpfile

Tags: node.js, npm, sharepoint, gulp, spfx

I am getting "Task '--ship' is not in your gulpfile" error while running  `gulp bundle –ship`.

[image]

My gulpfile.js

```
use strict;

const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');
build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

build.initialize(gulp);
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to refresh gulp installation with:

```
npm install gulp --save
```

or

```
npm install --save
```

to be sure your gulp isn't just broken.
Then you should be able to run

```
gulp clean
gulp build
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

and see if it's working now.

Comment: I 'd like to add that in case package-solution --ship fails, during build or bundle there are some messages warning with errors that you must fix. And it 'd be good if you added a developer section in your package-solution 

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6151

Answer (score 0):

In case if you installed npm `gulp` package globally `npm i -g gulp` you should use the next bundle command: `gulp bundle --ship` instead of `gulp bundle -ship`.

You can check your gulp global installation with `npm list -g --depth=0` commands.

Answer (score -1):

Your gulp file looks incorrect and has no tasks. A typical gulp task looks like the following, with the task name being 'watch' then action to perform.

```
gulp.task('watch',function() {
  gulp.watch('src/*.scss',['sass']);
});
```

See [this link](https://julienrenaux.fr/2014/05/25/introduction-to-gulp-js-with-practical-examples/) for some basic task recipes

Comment: The sp-build-web package contains all gulp tasks. This answer is not relevant to SPFx development.

Answer (score -1):

The command gulp package-solution when used with a space between package , - and solution will produce the  error. Just try the command without any space as below:

gulp package-solution